# iOS delete key not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have implemented UITextField delegate to prevent entering more than certain number of digits/characters in a textfield and it works. Problem is, after it has reached maximum number of digits/characters I can't even delete i.e. no key is responding not even delete key. How do I solve this? I need the delete key to work even after maximum number of characters have been entered. Below is my code:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField.text length] > 9) {
        textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:10];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you hit the delete button `[string length] == 0` and `range.length > 0`, so you can allow the deletion if you add this to the if:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if ([textField.text length] > 9&&!([string length] == 0 && range.length > 0)) {
        textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:10];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are considering only the current text, not the text if you were to actually allow the proposed edit:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *proposedText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    if ([proposedText length] > 9) {
        textField.text = [proposedText substringToIndex:10];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Also, I'd argue that you shouldn't have `textField.text = [proposedText substringToIndex:10];`, you should just return no rather than taking a partial change, but that's your choice.

Comment: The `textField.text = ` was probably necessary because he didn't check the proposed text. So the character entry was always delayed by one character count.

Comment: Thanks @Wain, it worked but when I tried deleting one digit/character the app terminated with an exception `index 8 out of bound, string length 7`. It worked after using this line in the if `if ([textField.text length] > 9&&!([string length] == 0 && range.length > 0))`

Comment: I'd just remove the `textField.text = [proposedText substringToIndex:10];` part and return NO to prevent the edit if it makes the string too long